# logic for dynamic String using split function

Tags: java, split

```
String x= "100,000"

String []y=x.split(",");

String z= y[0]+y[1] (give me expected result that is  100000)
```

my question is

if x is dynamic, may be sometime it has "2 comas". "3 comas" 
something like this (1,00,000 or 1,00,00,000 ) dynamic, then what can be used to separate comas and combine the String.

Comment: Which language do you use c++, java, c...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably just replace all the ',' by nothing instead of splitting the String.
In Java it would look like this:

```
s.replaceAll(",","");
```

If you want to do it with split then you need a loop that iterates over all the string parts and puts together the new string.

Example in Java:

```
String x= "100,000"
String []parts=x.split(",");
String z= "";

for(String part : parts){
    z+=part;
}
```

Comment: As it is java only `replaceAll` would suffice I guess.